# Are horizontal and horicontal pronounced the same in German?

Tags: pronunciation, spelling

In this [question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/265269/horicontal-etymology-mistaken-foreign-spelling-of-horizontal) in English Language and Usage, there is an enquiry about a spelling mistake that appears in certain technical papers that are of German authorship but are written in English.

My guess is that it is a German spelling mistake and that horizontal and horicontal wold be pronounced the same in German.

I am not a German speaker. Could you confirm or deny my theory?

Comment: I'm very skeptical: If it really originates from a German error, then from a translation mistake, not a German spelling mistake. As a German speaker, one is used to words where a German "z" is equivalent to an English "c". However, the biggest argument against this hypothesis is that the intuitive pronunciation of "horicontal" would contain a *k* sound.

Comment: I see. In that case I'll consider my theory disproved and modify my suggested answer on the English SE accordingly. I'm grateful for your help.

Answer (score 11):

"Horicontal" is not a German word. Nor does it match any German spelling pattern, not even an imported one. The standard pronunciation for the combination "co" is "ko" as in for example "Co-Sponsor". So "horicontal" would be pronounced "horikontal".
Might well be that back a hundred years ago (or more) some scholars would write it with a "c" because they didn't know any better.

Comment: On a quick note: It may be that *horicontal* was a common spelling before the spelling reform of 1901, but I cannot check this right now. Compare to *Konzern,* which was commonly spelt *Concern* before 1901.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft... that's not the best comparison though because in "concern" the soft "c" is followed by "e" which is how it is in French. The initial "c" was pronounced as a "k" (I believe). Anyhow, checking never hurts

Comment: @Wrzlprmft: I may be wrong but I don't think that "horizontal" was ever written with a *c* in German. In Greek (its origin) it was written with a *zeta*, in Latin this became a *z*. I cannot imagine a reason why it should have been written with a *c*... Hmm...

Comment: http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=DWB&lemid=GH12413

Comment: @Emanuel you are correct, the initical "c", like all instances of a c followed by an o, was pronounced as a "k".

Comment: @Chris: I just checked this and cannot find any evidence for *horicontal* in German either. So my guess was wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Emanuel's answer is correct. (Only the speculation in the last sentence is unfounded.) But that leaves the question why some German speakers would make this mistake. I think I can explain that.

It seems to me that this is an obvious example of a hypercorrection. In German, words of Latin origin eventually get *c* replaced by either *z* (before *e* and *i*) or *k* (before *a*, *o*, *u*). As a result, when replacing a German word of Latin origin by its English cognate, we have to replace *z* and *k* by *c*. (Zentrum -> centre, zirka -> circa, Kontakt -> contact, ...)

*Horizontal* superficially looks like a word of Latin origin, so it gets this treatment. Of course, the fact that the *z* in *horizontal* is before an *o*, not an *e* or *i*, should be clue enough that this is wrong. But in a few cases this largely automated process will trigger anyway.